# SQL Server, Using a stored procedure to insert data

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to insert data into my database by using a stored procedure but 3 of my columns are using the int identity type and I cannot insert. It keeps saying cannot do this whilst identity insert is off

Comment: The error message is about violation of Foreign Key constraint. Can you show the table details along with query produced this error

Comment: Provide more details on error message and table schema ,insert.Better way is to start from here:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

When IDENTITY_INSERT is on, it just means that you can put your own data in IDENTITY column. It doesn't disable the FK constraint you have on the table. You can delete the FK constraint, or disable it, and risk having logically inconsistent data in your DB, or you can fix your SP so you won't insert any duplicate values.

Comment: when IDENTITY_INSERT  is ON, not off, then you can put own data into identity column :)

Answer (score 0):

Something is amiss.  *Three* columns in a single table of type `Identity`?  I'm having difficulty imagining what they could represent, and I have to wonder where the natural keys are.

In any case, IDENTITY_INSERT isn't something you want to putz with casually.  It's an administrative feature to allow *ad hoc* changes to the data, for example bulk loading the database.

If you do actually know what the identities are (as input to your stored procedure) then the table is misdefined, because it's supposed to be the identity source.  If you don't know, or you're willing to let the table generate identity values, then you simply don't mention those columns in your `INSERT` statement.  At most, the generated values would be `OUTPUT` parameters to your stored procedure.

Comment: They're from other tables, They're in one table as a foreign key

Comment: @Zank, in that case, they are probably defined as IDENTITY in the other tables; that's where the identity values are generated.  If so, the table you're inserting should be recreated with the columns defined according to the same datatype as those other tables use (probably `INT NOT NULL`), replacing `IDENTITY` with `UNIQUE`.